# can i remove the effect of *:after for some of my css

Tags: css

I am not good with css , I took some library which have this below css.

```
*,
 *:before,
*:after {
box-sizing: inherit ; 
}
```

This is good for some views , but for some views its making them wrong and i dont need it for some of the views .

For example this button
[image]

the text inside it is usually in center, but because of this above css the text is going to the right ..

I tried to add a styleName to this button where i do

```
  .buttonStyle
  {
  box-sizing: unset !important ; 
  }
```

But its not working .

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Try *,
 *:before,
*:after {
box-sizing: border-box; width:100%;
}

Comment: *but because of this above css the text is going to the right* --> I don't think. I am pretty sure it's something else

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do it like this..

```
.buttonStyle:after, buttonStyle:before {
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

or you can use the content-box as per your need, but unset is not the right value for the box-sizing property.